# Which is faster, int to String or String to int?

Tags: java, android

This may seem like a fairly basic question, for which I apologise in advance.

I'm writing an Android app that uses a set of predefined numbers. At the moment I'm working with `int` values, but at some point I will probably need to use `float` and `double` values, too.

The numbers are used for two things. First, I need to display them to the user, for which I need a `String` (I'm creating a custom `View` and drawing the `String` on a `Canvas`). Second, I need will be using them in a sort of calculator, for which they obviously need to be `int` (or `float`/`double`).

Since the numbers are the same whether they are used as `String` or `int`, I only want to store them once (this will also reduce errors if I need to change any of them; I'll only need to change them in the one place).

My question is: should I store them as `String` or as `int`? Is it faster to write an `int` as a `String`, or to parse an `int` from a `String`? My gut tells me that parsing would take more time/resources, so I should store them as `int`s. Am I right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, your gut *may* be wrong (and I emphasise *may,* see my comments below on measuring). To convert a string to an integer requires a series of multiply/add operations. To convert an integer to a string requires division/modulo. It may well be that the former is faster than the latter.

But I'd like to point out that you should *measure, not guess!* The landscape is littered with the corpses of algorithms that relied on incorrect assumptions.

I would also like to point out that, unless your calculator is expected to do *huge* numbers of calculations each second (and I'm talking millions if not billions), the difference will be almost certainly be irrelevant.

In the vast majority of user-interactive applications, 99% of all computer time is spent waiting for the user to do something.

My advice is to do whatever makes your life easier as a developer and worry about performance if (and only if) it becomes an issue. And, just to clarify, I would suggest that storing them in *native* form (not as strings) would be easiest for a calculator.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am going to try storing them as int, as most of the comments seem to suggest is best for various reasons. Although I think I'll run a few benchmark tests anyway, just out of curiosity. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 6):

I did a test on  a 1 000 000 size array of int and String. I only timed the parsing and results says :

- Case 1, from int to String : 1 000 000 in an average of 344ms
- Case 2, from String to int : 1 000 000 in an average of 140ms

Conclusion, you're guts were wrong :) !

And I join the others saying, this is not what is going to make you're application slow. Better concentrate on making it simpler and safer.

Comment: Thank you! I am currently in the middle of yet another programming headache, and this reply just made me smile :-D

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that's not really relevant. What should matter more is type safety: since you have numbers `int` (or `float` and `double`) would force you to use numbers and not store "arbitrary" data (which `String` would allow to some extent).

Answer (score 2):

A human who is using the calculator will not notice a performance difference, but as others have said. Using strings as your internal representation is a bad idea since you don't get type safety in that case.

You will most likely get into maintenance problems later on if you decide to use strings.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing an application for mobile devices, where the memory comsumption is a huge deal.

Storing an `int` is cheap, storing a `String` is expensive. Go for `int`.

Edit: more explanation. Storing an `int` bteween `-2^31` and `2^31-1` costs 32 bits. No matter what the number is. Storing it in a `String` is 16 bits per digit in its base 10 representation.

Comment: How many numbers will a user enter into a calculator? 5? 10? Memory consumption won't be of importance. :)

Answer (score 1):

The best is to do a bench test. Write two loops

- one that converts 100000 units from numeric to String
- one that converts 100000 units from String to numeric

And measure the time elapsed by getting [System.currentTimeMillis()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) before and after each loop.

But personally, if I would need to do calculation on these numbers, I would store them in their native format (int or float) and I would only convert them to String for display. This is more a question of design and maintainability than a question of execution speed. Focusing on execution speed is sometime counterproductive: to gain a few µSec nobody will notice is not worth sacrifying the design and the robustness (of course, some compromise may have to be done when this is a question of saving a lot of CPU time). [This reading may interest you](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html).

Comment: Thanks. I've read the Android Best Practices documents several times, though not everything has stuck in my brain just yet :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's better design practice to have the view displayed to the user being derived from the underlying data, rather than the other way around - at some point you might decide to render the calculator using your own drawing functions or fixed images, and having your data as strings would be a pain here.

That being said, neither of these operations are particularly time consuming using modern hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing is a slow thing, printing a number is not. The internal representation as number allows you to compute, which is probably what you intend to d with your numbers. Storing numbers as, well, numbers (ints, floats, decimals) also takes up less space than their string representations, so … you'll probably want to go with storing them as ints, floats, or whatever they are.